# Understanding Attributes and Methods in Java

Tags: java

I have the basic idea down that we have a class that has an attribute and method; however, I am confused on how it specifically works. E.g. `c2.chat(c3);` I have a Cow that's equal to a Calf, and calling the chat() function on a Calf. Why do we use the chat() function in the Calf class vs. the chat() function in the Cow class? What is the c2 field in this call doing?

```
   class Cow{
        String say = "C";
        String speak(){
            return say;
        }
        void chat(Cow c1){
            System.out.println("A " + this.speak() + " B " + c1.speak());
        }
    }
    class Calf extends Cow{
        Calf(){ say = "H";}
        void chat(Cow c1){
            System.out.println("F " + this.speak() + " G " + c1.speak());
        }
    }
    class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Cow c1 = new Cow();
            Calf c3 = new Calf();
            Cow c2 = c3;
            c1.chat(c2);
            c2.chat(c3);
            c3.chat(c2);
            c1.chat(c3);
            c3.chat(c1);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
A C B H
F H G H
F H G H
A C B H
F H G C
```

Comment: What is your question finally ?

Comment: You use the `chat()` method in the `Calf` class if it has it's own unique functionality.  `c2` is a copy of `c3`, and this compiles because of inheritance.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ See last two lines of the text block.

Comment: @DrewKennedy thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your are using an existing method for a cow class, and calf derives from cow, the chat methods are different based on the properties of calf in comparison to a cow. Hence, the speak method can be used in both classes. Though they are both based on the fact they can speak, just in different ways. Another noticeable difference is the "say" variable is defined differently for a Calf vs. a Cow.

The c2 field is instantiating the Calf class to a new object, which is cow. If I understand correctly, this would be an utilization of polymorphism.